# How to plot the graphics within a prescribed domain?

Tags: graphics

Suppose I have a big circle and a series of small circle.

```
big = Circle[{0, 0}, 10];
smalls = Circle[{-5, -5}, #] & /@ Range[1, 5, 0.2];
Graphics[{big, smalls}]
```

[image]

For the small circles, I only want to show those line within the big circle, namely, using the big circle to trim the small circles. Are there some effective ways?

Comment: Take a look at `RegionIntersection` and friends.

Comment: I know `RegionIntersection` can do this. But I have to convey the curve to the region. Is there a direct method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are a couple possibilities:

$1$. Use [`Texture`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Texture):

```
Graphics[
    {
    Texture[Graphics[{smalls}, PlotRange->{{-10,10},{-10,10}}]],
    EdgeForm[Black],
    Polygon[
        CirclePoints[{0,0}, 10, 120],
        VertexTextureCoordinates -> Rescale[CirclePoints[{0,0},10,120], {-10,10}]
    ]
    }
]
```

[image]

$2$. Use [`ImageMultiply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageMultiply):

```
ImageMultiply[
    Graphics[smalls, PlotRange->{{-10,10},{-10,10}}],
    Graphics[{White, EdgeForm[Black], Disk[{0,0},10]}, Background->None]
]
```

[image]

*(Addendum)*

$3$. And one more possibility:

```
Graphics[{
    RegionIntersection[Disk[{0,0},10],#]& /@ smalls,
    big
}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using [`ContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html) with [`RegionFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html)

```
eqns = {x^2 + y^2 == 100, 
    Thread[(x + 5)^2 + (y + 5)^2 == Range[1, 5, 1/5]^2]} // Flatten;

ContourPlot[Evaluate@eqns, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10},
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2 <= 100],
 Frame -> False]
```

[image]